# Easy way to get a subset of the keyset of a TreeMap (in Java)

Tags: java, treemap

Is it possible to extract the top n (I use top because I believe a TreeMap is sorted) key elements from a TreeMap, without iterating using an Iterator object.

I can do the iteration but it's tedious to have to check for nulls etc.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? why only the top 10 keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you be checking for nulls?

If you use the [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) you can use [Iterables.limit](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)).

EDIT: For some reason the GCL page doesn't include `limit`, but it's in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) (which has effectively replaced the GCL) - it's still [`Iterables.limit`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the subset of keys from one key up to another using `.subMap(low,high).keySet()` or `.headMap(high).keySet()`.

Finding out the correct high key for the *n*th is harder, as there is no direct approach and iterating is the only sure-fire way.

(this code is *untested*)

```
public <K,V> SortedMap<K,V> subMap(SortedMap<K,V> map, int n) {
  Iterator<K> it = map.keySet().iterator();
  for (int i = 0; i<n && it.hasNext(); i++) {
    it.next();
  }
  if (it.hasNext()) {
    return map.headMap(it.next());
  } else {
    return map
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

[subMap method][1]

```
public NavigableMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey,boolean fromInclusive,K toKey,boolean toInclusive)
```

[1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap(K, boolean, K, boolean)

Comment: Nope: he doesn't know the values of toKey.